# Facebook localization & translation issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I was using ordinary facebook like buttons on my sites. I generated them using tool on developers site. For example, it might look like this:

```
...
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
...
```

It was working for me for a long time. But a problem appeared a few days ago. The code aboce causes javascript error. Suprisingly, the problem occures only in Chorme browser, Firefox and IE are OK. I tested different installation of Chrome but the problem seems to be everywhere.

I have found out that the problem is caused by localization string. If I use English language in the like button, it works perfect. Unfortunately, I want to use Czech language and it does not work.

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

I tried to use different strings available from [there](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml) and it seems that every language except Czech works great! How is it posible?

I know that I can use iframe but I am interested in the cause of the problem.

Comment: If that is causing an error, then it’s a problem on Facebook’s side, so you should report it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: What error do you get? I have just checked out a site with czech fb connect jssdk, and it works.

Comment: @IvanHanák I got syntax error. Now solved! I tested it on two computers with another version of Chorome, but the problem where on both of them. I cleared cache and now working! Strange behavior ...